# Undefined symbol using template

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I am getting a linker error building this code:

Exclude.h file

```
class IsExclude
{
    public:
        template<typename T>
        bool operator()(const T* par);
        virtual ~IsExclude() = 0;
};

IsExclude::~IsExclude() {}

class IsExcludeA : public IsExclude
{
    public:
        IsExcludeA(std::string toCompare) : toCompare_(toCompare)  {}
        template<typename T>
        bool operator()(const T* par)
        {
            return strcmp(par->Something, toCompare_.c_str() ) ? false : true ; 
        }
        ~IsExcludeA() {}
    private:
        std::string toCompare_;
};
```

In the same file:

```
/*
 * loop over a container of function objects
 * if at least one of them return true the function
 * return true, otherwise false
 * The function was designed to evaluate a set of
 * exclusion rule put in "and" condition.
 */
template<typename T,typename P>
bool isExclude( const T& cont, const P* toCheck )
{
    typename T::const_iterator pos;
    typename T::const_iterator end(cont.end());
    bool ret(false);
    for (pos = cont.begin(); pos != end; ++pos)
    {
        if ( (*pos)->operator()(toCheck) == true )
        {
            ret = true;
            pos = end;
        }
    }    
    return ret;
}
```

The cpp file where I use the previous call looks like this:

```
std::vector<IsExclude* > exVector;

exVector.push_back( new IsExcludeA(std::string("A")) );
exVector.push_back( new IsExcludeA(std::string("B")) );

if (isExclude(exVector,asset) == false)
{
     // Blah
}
```

The code compile fine but I got an error from the linker:
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
bool IsExclude::operator()(const __type_0*) MyFile.o

Do you have any hint or suggestions?

P.S. I am aware I need to clean up the vector in order to avoid memory leak. I can't use boost::shared_ptr with my compiler. Sigh!

Comment: `return strcmp(par->Something, toCompare_.c_str() ) ? false : true ; ` should be written as `return par->Something == toCompare;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `isExclude` function, you write :

```
if ( (*pos)->operator()(toCheck) == true )
```

This calls `IsExclude::operator()` which is declared but not defined, so the linker has a good reason to complain. It seems to me that you would *like* to have a polymorphic behavior on `operator()` but that you fell into the 'template functions cannot be virtual' trap.

It's hard to help you more without knowing what are your requirements, but maybe you should reconsider having a templated `operator()` and go for a *virtual* `operator()`.

Comment: I see! I think I need to reconsider my design. Thanks.